# Sentences with recent actions

Tags: perfect-constructions

If an action has just happened, I should use present perfect, right? (At least in BE)

Like: A friend come back and he is sweating, I can reply "What has happened?" right?

And:(fake story :)) If a guy disrespects me, should I say " What have you said to me, right now ?"

Comment: Your first example sounds natural, the second doesn't. If you can't believe he said something so disrespectful, you might ask "_What_ did you just say?" or "What was that you just said?"

Comment: Your second example is not idiomatic. Prefer: **What did you just say to me?**

Comment: @KateBunting Could you please explain me why present perfect is not natural in the second sentence?

Comment: I can't give any explanation other than 'it's not how we say it', I'm afraid.

Comment: What's happened/ Or What happened? Can both be used and, once again, this has zero to do with BrE or AmE.

Answer (score 1):

A better way of saying the first would be "What's happened?". It means the same, as "What's" is just an abbreviation of "What has", but a native speaker is more likely to say "What's" rather than "What has".

The second is not idiomatic. It should be along the lines of:
"What did you just say to me?" or simply "What'd you say?"